# PHP MySQL - Select members with where-clause statements from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I've been Googling for most of my day now but I can't seem to find the right answer. Maybe because I don't really know in which direction to look (join? exist?). What I have is 3 tables:

[image: Explanation table set-up]

---

There is a table named 'groups' and 'languages' containing the actual group- and language data but that's not important right now.

The user should be able to generate a list with all members, depending on the selected groups and/or languages. The groups/languages that the user selected are saved in two separate array's containing the IDs (`$aGroups` and `$aLangs`).

What I want/need is to `SELECT * FROM members WHERE ...`

And that's where I got stuck. I've tried joins, I've tried `IN()`, I've tried `EXIST` but nothing seems to work right.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select members by languages and groups, you can do something like this :

```
$query = "select * from members as m 
left join group_members as gm on gm.member_id = m.id 
left join language_members as lm on lm.member_id = m.id";
if(isset($aGroups)) {
  $query .= " where group_id in (".implode(",", $aGroups).")";
  if(isset($aLangs)) {
    $query .= " and language_id in (".implode(",", $aLangs).")";
  }
} 
elseif(isset($aLangs)) {
  $query .= " where language_id in (".implode(",", $aLangs).")";
}
```

Comment: This works great for the most part. There's one thing though: some records (members) show up twice (or more). And I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that some members speak 2 or more languages. Or are a member of 2 or more groups. Do you also know how to fix this?

Comment: Ok maybe I should've Googled before posting my comment. I added `GROUP BY m.id` at the end. Works great! Is this also the best way? Or are there other ways I should know of? Either way I'm marking your answer. Thanks for your help! (That goes for the other answers as well!)

Comment: @svdv22 If you need only the id, you could use "select distinct m.id from ...". If it's the case, "group by" will give the same result.

Comment: Nope, also need the name so went by GROUP BY. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need some brackets:

```
//assuming you have ids stored in $lang and $group
SELECT * FROM members WHERE (SELECT group_id FROM group_members WHERE member_id=members.id)='$group'
AND (SELECT lang_id FROM language_members WHERE member_id=members.id)='$lang'
```

The trick is "members.id", DB will call subquery for every member to find out if the condition for group and lang is met.

Comment: You should **ALWAYS** try avoiding using nested queries with mysql.

Comment: @svdv22 exactly. if you want some more information you can google `mysql nested queries`. you'll find a lot of questions & answers here on StackOverflow as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select m.* FROM members m, group_members gm, language_members lm
WHERE
lm.member_id=m.id AND
m.id=gm.member_id AND
<<<< START YOUR OWN WHERE HERE.
```

Comment: No, this is not the same as doing a left join but as doing an inner join

Comment: @leson Sonesson : now that you deleted your comment, mine seems odd ;)